# Powershell script returns only first value in Excel range

Tags: powershell

I'm getting some errors while trying to read Excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to read values in cells `B2` to `B15`, but am only getting back `B2`.

Can someone help fix my code, so that all the correct lines can be written as output? Please and thanks...

**Excel Table**

a-n

**PowerShell Code**

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\administrator\Book1.xlsx")
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$i = 2;
$data = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text 
$get = @{"$data"="value"}

foreach ($Key in ($get.GetEnumerator()))  {
    $i++;
    $Key.name
}
```

**Output**

I just get the first line of output, `a`, rather than the expected 14 lines from row 2-15, with the output being `a-n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that would save you a lot of time is to export from Excel into a CSV file, and in powershell you'll have really easy access to the data, and you could manipulate it really easily too. It doesn't look like your data is very complex, so I highly recommend you do this. However, here's a solution to the way you have it now:

Here lies the first problem in your code, though. As you can see, the `$i` is defined in this line:

```
$i = 2;
```

And in your `for` loop, you write:

```
foreach ($Key in ($get.GetEnumerator()))  {
    $i++;
    $Key.name
}
```

Note that this is mildly confusing. Usually, for-loops are either Iterator-Based (as your's is, using `in`), or, they are Range-Based, using the common range iterator `$i`. In your case, $i is an iterator but is used outside the loop to get data from your sheet. This should not be the case. Hence, the solution would be to put some of the lines outside your loop into your loop:

```
$i = 2;
$get = @{"$data"="value"}
foreach ($Key in ($get.GetEnumerator()))  {
    $data = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text 
    $i++;
    $Key.name
}
```

**Unfortunately**, after having tried this out, I realised that `$get.GetEnumerator` is a dictionary with only one line! This should be obvious from the way it is defined right above, I guess we both missed it. That explains why your code only ran once, rather than running more times, but only returning the first line (which I would have expected from before).

The solution is that you should change the for loop to be range-based. You already defined the variable you need for this, as `rowMax`. Here's all your code in working order:

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\administrator\Book1.xlsx")
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1")
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$get = @{"$data"="value"}

for ($i = 2; $i -le $rowMax; $i++)  {
    $data = $sheet.Cells.Item($i + 1, 2).text 

    $get[$data] = $sheet.Cells.Item($i + 1, 1).text
}
```

In dictionary `$get`, `$data` is your key according to:

```
$get = @{"$data"="value"}
```

However, you then add another variable called "$key". Is this not the same as `$data`? Or when you wrote `$data`, did you actually mean `$value`? I recommend you stick use either `$data` or `$key` as the dictionary key, but not both.

**EDIT:** changed the code according to what we discussed in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time to give such well explanation here. Just some noticed, the "<" symbol in powershell is "-lt".  After I try  `$get = @{"$data"="value"}

for ($i = 2; $i -lt $rowMax; $i++)  {
    $data = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text 
} `  **The output shows nothing. May I know which I key in wrong in the code please?  Please and thanks...**

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too, oops ^-^ The reason the output does not show anything is that you did not add anything to output. After the one you posted, inside the `for` loop, try adding just `$data` on a new line. This will output what you want, hopefully.

Comment: If you want to add to the dictionary, you could write this line: `$get[$data] = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,1).text`. That should add everything to the dictionary, and you can output it outside the `for` loop by writing `$get` at the very end of your script.

Comment: Thanks you so much ! The output shows **a - l** accordingly.  However, my excel table was **a - n**. May I know was there a limitation to read the data ...? or the code I have written wrong in some parts? `$get = @{"$data"="value"}

for ($i = 2; $i -lt $rowMax; $i++)  {
    $data = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text 
 $data;
}` Please and thanks really....

Comment: Try using `-le` instead of `-lt`, and try putting `$i=1` in the loop, and then in `$sheet.Cells.Item`, turn `($i,2)` into `($i + 1, 2)`. Also, upvotes are always appreciated ;)

Comment: I take back the thing about `$i = 1`. Keep it at `$i=2` That will probably output a line too early. Do the two other things instead (two things = 2 new lines ;) )

Comment: Thank you for your precious time to answer my question. The code works ! I have upvotes your post. ^.^  **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score**

Comment: @DDC haha, still appreciated! I'm glad it works. Thanks for being clear with your problems too, it helps for me to solve them :P